# Either login form on every page or form that redirects to page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app, there are a lot of pages that don't require you to be signed in to view. For example, the profile page of a certain user. My current session logic redirects back to the previous page IF that page requires you to be signed in. If it doesn't though, like the profile page, and you click sign in and sign in, it just takes you to the url specified in my SessionsController action. This brings me to a crossroads. Either I need a modal on every page (in `layouts/application.html.erb`) that has the sessions form so a user can click Sign In, the model will open, and when they sign in it just refreshes the page pretty much so the user can stay on the current page. However, I'm trying that now and getting a few errors. The other option is to have the individual login page but no matter which page you come from within the app, it will redirect you back to. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to write the code for this.

Here is the code I have currently where I'm trying to have the Session form on every page through a modal.

```
**SessionsController #create action**

def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    sign_in user
    redirect_back_or request.original_url
  else
    flash.now[:error]  = "Invalid email/password combination."
    render 'new'
  end
end

**layouts/application.html.erb**

<% unless signed_in? %>
...modal code
  <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) %>
      <%= text_field ... %>
      <%= password_field .... %>
      <%= submit button %>
  <% end %>
... # I've shorted the code here obviously
<% end %>
```

This Form works fine on the `/login` page: `match '/login', to: "sessions#new", via: "get"`

However, when I use this form on other pages, I get this error:

```
`Missing template public/error with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. `
```

and this page is goes to it :

```
http://localhost:3000/sessions
```

How can I make this Sessions form work on every page of the site?? Thanks

**Update**

After playing with it more, I realized that the form works when I change the code in the SessionController to

```
redirect_back_or profile_path(user)
```

instead of the current

```
redirect_back_or request.original_url
```

How can I redirect back to the current page I'm on instead of specifying a specific page like the profile page???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. Please still answer if you have a better solution.

```
redirect_back_or :back
```

Comment: make sure you redirect_back_or :back or back!